Convenient way to observe navigation in Flutter go_router
In go_router, is there a way to read the current route once a navigation event happens (read the route before it changes). Similar to auto_router's onNavigattion.
I tried getting that from the GoRouterState instance I get in redirect from , ie.
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
   redirect: (context, state) => // ...

But failed. state has only information about the new route (where is it navigating to).
I also tried extending NavigationObserver and override all of didPop, didPush, didRemove, didReplace, but it seems hacky.
Is there a more straightforward way that I'm missing?
